# Catch with multiple exceptions not catching exceptions in obfuscated build

Tags: java, try-catch, proguard, obfuscation

I have used catch block with multiple exceptions , Which is working fine in unobfuscated build, But not catching exception in obfuscated build.

I am using proguard-maven-plugin

```
try {
  ...
} catch (ServletException | IOException e){
  ...
}
```

Is there any proguard rule i need to add for this?

Because its working fine When i write my code as

```
try {
  ...
} catch (ServletException e) {
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Proguard should not have effect on this. Maybe it is caused by something unrelated. Are you sure that the two builds you are comparing differ only in proguard being and not being used? Also, does it make any difference if you have two catch blocks each for single exception type?

Comment: Yes, two builds are comparing differ only in proguard.
And Its working fine when I write two catch blocks each for single exception.

Comment: Have you tried adding -keepattributes Exceptions? The docs says that "Specifies the exceptions that a method may throw. Compilers may use this information to enforce catching them."

Comment: Yes I have added -keepattributes Exceptions

Comment: Apparently, it's an [open bug on Proguard](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/607/?SetFreedomCookie).

You might want to add a comment on the bug to provide the team with your feedback.

Comment: Could you share proguard version and its configuration which you are using? Also I suggest you to try to add Throwable in your catch block and see if there is any other exception occurring as mentioned in proguard's bug.

Comment: I am throwing same exception in obfuscated build and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There can be a bug from Proguard. 
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/607/
Unfortunately no solution was provided.
I suggest to avoid multi-catch until it's not fixed if possible.

Comment: I have worked with the same codebase reported in the above defect 607 and can report that as of Proguard Gradle plugin 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.1' the defect still exists. Sadly, with Proguard we have to avoid Java 7 & 8 multi-catch (E | E) feature.  Using "-dontpreverify" can suppress the problem, but this led us to further downstream effects.

Answer (score -1):

Multi catch exception can be used when there are chances of raising exceptions without any relation(parent-child), something like `IOException` and `ArithmeticException` and `NullPointerException`. But you can't use multi catch block with the exception like `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` because `IOException` is the parent of `FileNotFoundException`.

Multi catch block is given in java7 just for programmer's convenience. It doesn't affect the execution time.

Comment: Please read question once again its about proguard and Obfuscation